# Rails.application - Questions on Rails Internal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working through "Learn Ruby on Rails" by Daniel Kehoe, and I came up on this piece of code:

In **config/environments/development.rb**:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
    password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
  }

  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  # Send email in development mode?
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

This made me think of two questions.

1. In **config/secrets.yml**, we defined environmental variables to use for sensitive data. For example, `email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]`. Why not just use ERB in the **config/environments/development.rb** file directly? The only reason I can think of is that development.rb doesn't get run through the ERB preprocessor. Is that the case? Just trying to understand the design decision here.
2. I am guessing that, since we are using the dot notation, `Rails` is an object. Can someone explain to me how that works? Is this the "top" of my rails application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I believe this is done this way because you wouldn't necessarily store it in an environment variable for both development and production environments.  For `development`, you may just store it directly in the file but for `production` you may store it in an environment variable, it gives you more flexibility to do it this way.
2. `Rails` is actually a module, not a class.  You can see how it works by looking at the `Rails` source code:

   https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails.rb